# Do I need an EMI Input Filter if source is within PCB?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emi-filtering

Newbie here.

I'm designing a circuit based on PoE ([MYBSP0122BABFT](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdetail?partno=MYBSP0122BABFT)). It has a 12VDC output. It will be used on various loads mounted on same PCB.

One of the loads is a 12VDC to 24VDC module ([TEL 12-1215](https://www.tracopower.com/int/model/tel-12-1215)). Per module datasheet, it recommends an EMI input filter. Is this applicable to my design? I'm thinking no as module source is within same PCB.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best answer is probably that it depends - If the current PCB source contains enough components which would act as filters (inductors, decoupling capacitors of various capacitance etc.) then it is likely to be fine... you can compare the recommended filter to your current PCB layout and calculate the reactance to ground for various different frequencies.

If you have no filtering components already on the PCB then you should add them per the manufacturer's recommended filter, since it would be designed to remove frequencies which could damage the internal components or cause weird resonance issues.

For the most part though, filtering components are usually quite cheap, and implementing them on the board as per the datasheet is trivial, so unless you have a compelling reason not to, you should add the filter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. also got feedback from TRACO - won't hurt to add filter.